# How to put php created content into targeted specific div?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Noob here! I'd like to run a simple post-loop on a wordpress homepage. If I write the loop in my functions.php file and then load the homepage, the result of the query is shown at the top of the mainpage.

Now I would like to see the result of the loop in a specific div. The reason for that is, that I would like to use a pagebuilder for most of the sites content first and then see the loop.

TLDR; How can I make the content created by a php function be displayed/loaded into a specific div container? Is it even possible?

I've tried creating the div and putting the shortcode for my function inside of it but wordpress wouldn't even allow me to save the changes.

in functions.php:

```
function show(){

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page' => '30',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
     );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID() );
echo'<div><div class="numbertext">1</div>';
echo $images = wp_get_attachment_image( $query_images->posts->ID, 'full' );
echo'<div class="title">'; 
the_title(); 
echo'</div></div>';
endwhile; 
};
add_shortcode( 'imgshow', 'show' );
```

Then in Pagebuilder:

```
<div id="imgcontainer">[imgshow]<div>
```

So for each img the query finds, I expect the loop to create some div boxes with the images and their titles in it.

Comment: you never should output any content directly from functions.php file unless ajax

Comment: Why and where were you not allowed to make the changes?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you! "[...]just call it where ever you need it[...]" this is kinda what I tried with the shortcode. I expected the shortcode to run the function in the div "imgcontainer".

Comment: @Adder I can't tell why because the message given is not explaining anything else but "Update failed".
I get the message after editing in "pages". I use the page builder plugin by siteorigin.

Comment: @JayWadhwa Alright, I'll keep that in mind, thank you! If there is another way to output the content, I'm glad to find out :)

Comment: I just found [this](https://siteorigin.com/thread/updating-failed-on-page-builder/) when googling for the error.

Comment: @Adder So you say the method I used should work and it is the page builder plugin that causes the issue?

Comment: I'm no wordpress expert, but what you are doing might work IMHO. If you can't upload your changes, then of course it cannot prove itself to work. Try the method of disabling your other plugins till the page builder works again, or at least check that you don't have the plugin causing issues that is mentioned in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but a little off on your shortcode syntax.  One thing to remember with shortcodes is you always have to return content, as opposed to echoing it.  I haven't tested this, but this should work.

```
function show(){

ob_start(); // should usually start a shortcode with an output buffer

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page' => '30',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
     );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID() ); ?>

// You don't have to echo divs you can use html tags in PHP

     <div class="numbertext">1</div>
      <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
       <div class="title"> 
         <?php the_title(); ?>
       </div>
     </div>

<?php
endwhile; 

// put the content in a variable creating from the output buffer
$content = ob_get_clean(); 

// return the content
return $content;

};
add_shortcode( 'imgshow', 'show' );
```